# Save pages of pdf in an array for multiple pages

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, uipageviewcontroller

How can i save pages of pdf in an array to display it in uipageviewcontroller.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this will help.

This code assumes two things:

- You have added the Quartz framework to your project, and
- You have an NSURL object describing the location of a PDF document.

First, create a PDFDocument object, initialized with the contents of the PDF document:

```
// Make a new PDF document object with the contents of the file at the specified URL.
PDFDocument * myPDF = [[PDFDocument alloc]initWithURL:fileURL];
```

Then, ask the PDF document object how many pages it contains.

```
// Get the page count of the PDF document object.
NSUInteger pdfPageCount = [myPDF pageCount];
```

Use a temporary NSMutableArray to hold the pages.

```
// Make a new mutable array to hold the document's pages.
NSMutableArray * mutablePageArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:pdfPageCount];
```

Use a "for" loop to flip through the pages of the PDF document. For each trip through the loop, add the page from the PDF document's page index which corresponds to the loop's counter.

```
// Add each page of the PDF document to the array.
for (int i=0; i < pdfPageCount; i++) {
    [mutablePageArray addObject:[myPDF pageAtIndex:i]];
}
```

Lastly, since you wanted an NSArray, make an NSArray from the contents of the NSMutableArray.

```
// Convert the NSMutableArray to an NSArray, then return it.
NSArray * pageArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:mutablePageArray];
```

Some notes:
I'm still kind of new to Objective-C, so there are probably some memory management things you'll want to do in this code. Also, note this is from a Mac OS point of view, but I don't think there's anything inherently Mac-only in the code. At the least, it should get you pointed in the right direction.